# How to use replace in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, replace

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with this code:

```
$("#replace").text().replace("cat","dog");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not replacing the text of the element. You're just getting it and replacing the text but not updating the `DOM`.

```
$("#replace").text($('#replace').text().replace("cat","dog"));
```

OR

```
$("#replace").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace("cat", "dog");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use callback function for `.text()`:

> function
>   Type: Function( Integer index, String text ) => String
>   A function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.

```
$("#replace").text(function(i,oldtext){
   return oldtext.replace("cat","dog");
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace function with jQuery object not on text.

```
$("#replace").text($("#replace").text().replace("cat","dog"));
```